# Append rows to a dataframe with one column populated from a vector and others having fixed values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 6 columns which already has some data in it. Now I want to append rows to it with the first column being populated with all the items in a list, 2nd,3rd, and 4th columns having the same string value for all rows and the 5th and 6th having another same string value for all rows.

Example:

```
dataframe.ex <-data.frame( V1 = sample(c("a","b","c")), V2 = sample(c("x","y","z")), V3 = sample(c("he","she","it")), V4 = sample(c("A","B","C")), V5 = rep("a1",3), V6 = rep("m",3))

     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
1    c    y    it    B   a1    m
2    b    z   she    C   a1    m
3    a    x    he    A   a1    m
```

I have a vector which contains 3 values

```
vector.addrows.ex <- c("d","e","f")
```

The values I want to be populated in columns V2:V4 for all the rows are the same ex. `"etc"` .The final two columns would take the same values that are in the other rows.

So finally the dataframe would look like:

```
     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
1    c    y    it    B   a1    m
2    b    z   she    C   a1    m
3    a    x    he    A   a1    m
4    d    etc  etc   etc a1    m
5    e    etc  etc   etc a1    m
6    f    etc  etc   etc a1    m
```

Comment: Why do `e d f` appear in that order?

Comment: This is just an example that I created using sampling. Sorry for the confusion. I can fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
d1 <- data.frame(setNames(as.list(rep(c('etc', 'a1', 'm'), c(3, 1, 1))), 
         names(dataframe.ex)[-1]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rbind(dataframe.ex, cbind(V1=vector.addrows.ex , d1))
```

Comment: Is it possible to use row.names of our choosing to the dataframe created with cbind?

Comment: @ag14 Yes, after you have done with `rbind` i.e. `d2 <- rbind(...); row.names(d2) <- yourrownames`